# Function to find if a menu item is available at the moment or not in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Item is available at certain day of time. I want to find if item is available at current time. 
For ex: item : dosa, available timestring: is 10:00-12:00 ,17:40 - 20:30,7:00-8:45.
function takes two parameters(item,timestring);

I am stuck at point and not knowing how to move further can anyone please help me..

```
function Available(item, str){
    var currentTime = new Date(),
    currentHour = currentTime.getHours(),
    currentSecs = currentTime.getSeconds(),
    currentMsecs = currentTime.getTime();
    var a = str.split(',');
    var b = [];
    var ln = a.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < ln; i++){
        b[i] = a[i].split('-');
        console.log(b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: the next step is to create the Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of problem you wanted to check whether urs item is available on current time or not. so for this i am using current date but just chaing hours and minutes according to input . Hope it will help

```
 function Available(item, str){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    console.log(currentTime);
    var a = str.split(',');
    var b = [];
    var ln = a.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < ln; i++){
        b= a[i].split('-');
        startTime=time1(b[0]);
        endTime =time1(b[1]);
        if ((currentTime.getTime() > startTime.getTime()) && (currentTime.getTime() < endTime.getTime()))
       {
           return("yes")
       }
    }
    return("No");
}  


function time1(time){
   var currentTime = new Date();
   var get_time= time.split(":");
   currentTime.setHours(get_time[0]);
   currentTime.setMinutes(get_time[1]);
    return (currentTime);
}
console.log(Available('Dosa',"10:00-12:00 ,13:00 - 20:30,7:00-8:45"));
```

Comment: Thanks Roli !! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/e6wu7jcy/

```
function available(item, str){
    var currentTime = new Date(),
        currentHour = currentTime.getHours(),
        currentMins = currentTime.getMinutes(),
        zones = str.split(","),
        isavailable = false;

    for(i = 0; i < zones.length; i++){
        var zone = zones[i],
            starttime = zone.split("-")[0],
          endtime = zone.split("-")[1],
          sh = starttime.split(":")[0],
          sm = starttime.split(":")[1],
          eh = endtime.split(":")[0],
          em = endtime.split(":")[1];

       if(parseInt(currentHour) > parseInt(sh) && parseInt(currentHour) < parseInt(eh)){
        isavailable = true;
        break;
       }else if(parseInt(currentHour) == parseInt(sh)){
        if(parseInt(currentMins) > parseInt(sm)){
          isavailable = true;
          break;
         }
       }else if(parseInt(currentHour) == parseInt(eh)){
        if(parseInt(currentMins) < parseInt(em)){
          isavailable = true;
          break;
         }
       }
    }
   return isavailable;
}

alert(available("dosa","10:00-16:05,16:55-20:30,7:00-8:45"));
```

Comment: Hi Harry, there is little problem in your code that when I have a string as
(14:00-14:30) and currently the time is passed so it gives 'true' result but as per the condition is should return false..

I have done little change in your code as per need:
<code>
else if(parseInt(currentHour) == parseInt(sh) || parseInt(currentHour) == parseInt(eh))
       {
        if(parseInt(currentMins) > parseInt(sm) && parseInt(currentMins) < parseInt(em)){
          isavailable = true;
          break;
         }
       }</code>

Comment: O yes i didnt test the same hour for both start and end.